# How to specify fields for $plus->people->get('me') call?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-oauth

With [Google API PHP client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) library I use the following code, which works well and prints lot of information about the user, who authorizes my application via OAuth2:

```
<?php

require_once('google-api-php-client-1.1.7/src/Google/autoload.php');

const TITLE = 'My amazing app';
const REDIRECT = 'https://example.com/myapp/';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(TITLE);
$client->setClientId('REPLACE_ME.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('REPLACE_ME');
$client->setRedirectUri(REDIRECT);
$client->setScopes(array(Google_Service_Plus::PLUS_ME));
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
                error_log('The session state did not match.');
                exit(1);
        }

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: ' . REDIRECT);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken() && !$client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        try {
                $me = $plus->people->get('me'); # HOW TO SPECIFY FIELDS?
                $body = '<PRE>' . print_r($me, TRUE) . '</PRE>';
        } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
                error_log($e);
                $body = htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage());
        }
        # the access token may have been updated lazily
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
        $state = mt_rand();
        $client->setState($state);
        $_SESSION['state'] = $state;
        $body = sprintf('<P><A HREF="%s">Login</A></P>',
            $client->createAuthUrl());
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
        <TITLE><?= TITLE ?></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
        <?= $body ?>
        <P><A HREF="<?= REDIRECT ?>?logout">Logout</A></P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

However I need less info than returned by the above script.

When entering just the fields I am interested in at the [People: get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) "API explorer":

```
id,gender,name,image,placesLived
```

[image: screenshot 1]

this again works well and prints only the specified fields:

[image: screenshot 2]

**MY QUESTION:**

How to specify the fields in the above `$me = $plus->people->get('me');` call?

After studying [1.1.7/src/Google/Service/Plus.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/1.1.7/src/Google/Service/Plus.php) with the code:

```
/**
 * Get a person's profile. If your app uses scope
 * https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login, this method is 
 * guaranteed to return ageRange and language. (people.get)
 *
 * @param string $userId The ID of the person to get the profile for. The
 * special value "me" can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
 * @param array $optParams Optional parameters.
 * @return Google_Service_Plus_Person
 */
public function get($userId, $optParams = array())
{
  $params = array('userId' => $userId);
  $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
  return $this->call('get', array($params), "Google_Service_Plus_Person");
}
```

I have tried the following PHP code:

```
const FIELDS = 'id,gender,name,image,placesLived';

$me = $plus->people->get('me', array('fields' => urlencode(FIELDS)));
```

but for some reason it prints a lot of `:protected` strings:

```
Google_Service_Plus_Person Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => urls
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [aboutMe] => 
    [ageRangeType:protected] => Google_Service_Plus_PersonAgeRange
    [ageRangeDataType:protected] => 
    [birthday] => 
    [braggingRights] => 
    [circledByCount] => 
    [coverType:protected] => Google_Service_Plus_PersonCover
    [coverDataType:protected] => 
    [currentLocation] => 
    [displayName] => 
    [domain] => 
    [emailsType:protected] => Google_Service_Plus_PersonEmails
    [emailsDataType:protected] => array
    [etag] => 
    [gender] => male
    ...
```

Also I have tried just appending the fields after `me`:

```
$me = $plus->people->get('me?fields=' . urlencode(FIELDS)));
```

but get the 404 error:

> Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me%3Ffields%3Did%252Cgender%252Cname%252Cimage%252CplacesLived:
>   (404) Not Found

**UPDATE:** I have created [Issue #948](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/948) at GitHUb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify which fields to get from the G+ API, you just have to specify a `fields` member in the options array. So actually you got very close to the solution:

```
$me = $plus->people->get('me', array('fields' => 'id,gender,name,image,placesLived'));
```

You don't even have to `urlencode`, as it is a default safety feature of the library itself.

The thing that might have tricked you is, that the `Google_Service_Plus_Person` class contains all the possible fields a protected members, not regarding the actual fields that were sent by the API. Not included fields will be empty in the object. As always, protected members should not be used in any way by the user of the class.

You, as the user of the library should only use public members, such as `$me->getPlacesLived()` and `$me->getId()`. Dumping whole objects is a nice tool during development, but in production calling the public interface is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you, but how to get for example `givenName`? I try `($me->getName())['givenName']` but get syntax error. The `($me->getPlacesLived())[0]['value']` does not compile either.

Comment: That would be `$me->getName()->getGivenName()`. Places lived is `$me->getPlacesLived()->getPrimary()` or `$me->getPlacesLived()->getValue()` to get the array.

Comment: `$me->getName()->getGivenName()`works well, but unfortunately, I get: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getPrimary() on a non-object` and `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object` for the other 2 suggestions. Maybe because it is an array of places?

Comment: Right, the library is a bit lacking of documentation. `$me->getPlacesLived()` returns an array of objects having getValue() and getPrimary() methods. Listing them all: `foreach ($me->getPlacesLived() as $place) print_r($place->getValue());`